# [MongoDB]Although the query doesn't contain $literal, error message shows $literal is not supported

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, tableau-api, aws-documentdb

I want to use Tableau to analysis some data which from AWS DocumentDB.
I use the MongoDB BI connector and the network access is successful.
But when I open the worksheet in Tableau.
Some fields have no problems but some fields don't work well.
The error details are as follows:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.13.3]error running aggregation: Aggregation project operator not supported: '$literal'
SELECT SUM(1) AS `sum_Number of Records_ok`
FROM `OrderGroup`
HAVING (COUNT(1) > 0)
```

As you can see the SQL query doesn't contain `$literal`.
And the `$literal` is also supported by AWS DocumentDB.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html
Thank you very much for read my question.

Comment: Try to change `SUM(1)` to `SUM(column_name)`. Same for `Count(1)` to `Count(*)` Also, did you miss `GROUP BY field_name` ?

Comment: $literal is not supported in DocumentDB

Answer (score 0):

$literal support was added to DocumentDB in Oct 2021 (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/10/amazon-documentdb-adds-additional-mongodb-compatibility-apis/).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add more context to your answer, clarifying **how** to solve the problem instead of only pointing out **why** it happened. At its current state, your answer is unclear about what OP should do in order to solve the issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31097898)